# Why it is impossible to drag an image into UV/Image Editor and Node Editor?

Tags: uv, node-editor, uv-image-editor

A strange thing happened.
On my best computer (Windows 8.1, CPU i7 with 32 GB RAM and 3 GTX770 onboard) it is impossible to drag an image into UV/Image Editor and Node Editor. The mouse pointer is a denied symbol...
On my iMac this works.
I tried to reinstall and set as Default Settings but nothing...
Can you help me?
Thank you.

Andrea

Comment: not sure, but my guess is that it is a windows thing.

Comment: It works for me in Windows 8.1

Comment: It works for me on windows 10

Comment: What format is the image?

Comment: I tried with png and jpg... But with my iMc it works correctly!

Comment: David, maybe it is that... I want to make some test in Windows...

Comment: Maybe it is inhibited the ability to change the Compatibility Mode... I read that it is possible also with other softwares...

Answer (score -3):

I do not believe it is. You will need to add an "image texture" node, then select "open image". From there, locate your image. If it is a video, add a "movie clip" node and do the same. Hope this helps!

Comment: It is possible just to drag images into the UV/Image editor, the compositor (a new node will be created).

Comment: Of course. I know this. But it is the drag and drop method that does not work ...